# Setting a TextField's text from a document class file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've searched for a while, and nothing is working for me. I'm trying to make an idle game with my friend (who's doing graphics), and I'm just learning AS3 so I thought it'd be an easy-ish project to start with. I don't know how to make a health textbox that outputs the remaining health left. I searched for at least an hour and nothing I found has worked. Here's all my coding. I have numbers embedded for the textbox. The textbox's instance name is "health" so it's not too hard to find.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public var originalValue:Number = 10;
        public var remainingValue:Number = uint(originalValue);
        public var clickDamage:Number = 1;
        public var health:TextField = String(originalValue);
        public var moneyCount:Number=0;
        public var mineralValue:Number=5;
        public var destroyedCount:Number=0;

        mineral.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeDamage);
        public function takeDamage(e:Event):void
        {
            remainingValue = remainingValue - clickDamage;
            if (remainingValue <= 0) {
                remainingValue = originalValue;
                moneyCount += mineralValue;
                destroyedCount++;
            }
            health.text=String(remainingValue);
        }
    }
}
```

All I have for symbols so far is my textbox(health) and my button(mineral). Also, what's the difference between an instance name for a textbox symbol, and the instance name for the textbox inside? Sorry if it's a bad question, I'm just really confused and it's ticking me off because I've been trying to work around this problem for a while.

Comment: So what do I do with the line? Whenever I run the program, nothing shows up next to my static "Health:" text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is a lack of understanding of how class files work.   I've reworked your class file below and added some comments:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public var originalValue:Number = 10;
        public var remainingValue:Number = 10; //no need to convert to uint
        public var clickDamage:Number = 1;
        public var health:TextField; //you can't assign a string to a text field var //health = String(originalValue);
        public var moneyCount:Number=0;
        public var mineralValue:Number=5;
        public var destroyedCount:Number=0;

         //mineral.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeDamage);
         //in class files, you can't have lines of code outside of methods/functions create a constructor like below:

        //the constructor function must match the name of class, and will run whenever you create an instance of this class
        public function Main(){
            mineral.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeDamage);
            health.text = originalValue; //now assign the text to the text field
            //this assumes you have a text field on the main timeline with the instance name of "health"
        }

        public function takeDamage(e:Event):void
        {
            remainingValue = remainingValue - clickDamage;
            if (remainingValue <= 0) {
                remainingValue = originalValue;
                moneyCount += mineralValue;
                destroyedCount++;
            }
            health.text= remainingValue.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

If (as may be gleamed from comment in your question), you have your health text field encapsulated in a symbol/movie clip, you'll need to access it like so:

```
myHealthSymbolInstanceName.myHealthTextBoxInstance.text = value;
```

Comment: Do I have any problems with my instances? I understand the class set up more now, but nothing still comes up. I'm using a dynamic textbox (it's blank). Last time I made a small program (like a year ago) I realized I didn't even make a class separate in another .as file, so it's still a bit confusing with the Document classes and everything. Do both the textbox and the button need to be symbols? I have them both as symbols with separate instance names, but nothing I've done has worked. I'll probably end up doing more tutorials before making a game because I realize how much work I still need.

Comment: Well, first thing you need to do is make sure your class file is actually being used.  Put this line inside the constructor `trace("Im here")` and see if you get the message in the output window when you run.    You've put in the correct path to the class file in flashPro?

Comment: Next thing is figure out your scope to the health text box.  Did you drag a text field onto the main timeline and give it an instance name of "health"?  or did convert the text field into a symbol movie clip and then give that the name of "health"?  If the latter, then you still need to give the text field (inside the symbol) an instance and access it like so: `symbolName.textFieldName.text = "my text";`

Comment: My Document class is "Main.as" and that's where all my coding is. I traced "I'm here" in the constructor but nothing showed up. So I must have messed something up.

Comment: I created a textbox symbol with the instance of "healthBar" and then dragged it onto the screen and gave it "health" so I changed the coding to "healthBar.health.text ="

Comment: In the "Class" property of your flash project, make sure it says: "Main"  (leave off the .as)  That will by default look for the Main.as file in the same directory as your .fla  - click the pencil icon beside it to see if it find it.

Comment: I hit the checkmark (Adobe Flashpro 5) on the Document Class (in advanced Actionscript 3 settings) when I typed in "Main.as" and it said "A definition for the document class can not be found in the classpath, so one will be automatically generated upon export."

Comment: Leave off the ".as" and just type in `Main`

Comment: Yeah it found it. It brought me to the Main.as subfile

Comment: Yes, thank you. I should be able to handle the other text fields now as well. Thanks for taking the time to clear it up. :) It's making a lot more sense now.